# Live search utilizando React-Redux

Tags: react, redux

Olá, estou tentando criar um live search com o Redux, porém ele somente da o match com a palavra completa. Qual é o melhor método de realmente retornar para a minha tabela, nesse caso, somente os valores que a string em pesquisar contém?

Table

````
  const brandsList = useSelector(state => state.brands.brandList);
            <TableBody>
                {brandsList.slice(0, rowsPerPage).map((brand, i) => (
                  <TableRow className={classes.tableRow} hover key={i}>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Typography variant="body1">{brand.name}</Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Typography variant="body1">{brand.CNPJ}</Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Typography variant="body1">{brand.email}</Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Typography variant="body1">{brand.address}</Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Link to={`/brand/${brand.id}`}>
                        <IconButton aria-label="edit">
                          <EditIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                      </Link>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>```

Reducer

case fromTypes.SEARCHING_BRANDS:
      const {value} = action;
      const works = state.brandList.filter(item => item.name === value);
      return {
        ...state, value, works
      }
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código fornecido está incompleto, mas dá para perceber o que está acontecendo.

```
const works = state.brandList.filter(item => item.name === value);
```

Essa linha filtra o array brandList com itens cujo name seja idêntico ao value.
Se você quiser filtrar os itens cujo name inclua o value, então:

```
const works = state.brandList.filter(item => item.name.includes(value));
```

Você provavelmente também vai querer ignorar se as letras estão maúsculas e/ou minúsculas. Para isso, utilize **toLowerCase()** no name e no value.